# How i can add arguments when i navigate to another fragment?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

Right now i show my dialog fragment like this:

```
viewModel.onMoreMenuClickEvent.observe(this, Observer { event ->
    event.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { menuItems ->
        dialogFragment = BottomMenuDialog.newInstance(menuItems = menuItems).also {
            it.setTargetFragment(this, MORE_MENU_REQUEST_CODE)
            activity?.showDialogFragment(it)
        }
    }
})
```

In my `nav_graph.xml` i added dialog:

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/bottomMenuDialog"
    android:name="com.mandarine.sai.features.menu.BottomMenuDialog"
    android:label="BottomMenuDialog" />
```

And write navigation fun:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.bottom_menu_dialog)
```

But how i can add menuItems which i send in `newInstance` and `it.setTargetFragment(this, MORE_MENU_REQUEST_CODE)`?

Also here is code of my `newInstance()`:

```
fun newInstance(
    menuId: String = "",
    menuItems: List<MenuItemData>
): BottomMenuDialog {
    return BottomMenuDialog().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(KEY_ID, menuId)
            putSerializable(KEY_ITEMS, ArrayList(menuItems))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check android documentation

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

on

Define destination arguments

Example:

In your xml set arguments tag

[image]

and when you get de action, send de argument

[image]

Check id action naming

Also

In your receiving destination’s code, use the getArguments() method to retrieve the bundle and use its contents. When using the -ktx dependencies, Kotlin users can also use the by navArgs() property delegate to access arguments.

[image]